# Is there any way to invoke a Cortana response without user input?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, user-experience, cortana

I have an app I am working on for Windows 10 which should notify a user when external data reaches a certain threshold.

While I can simply use Windows Notifications (and will fall back on them), I'd really like to do more integration with Cortana. (Voice activation and natural searching will be available.)

Is there any way to have Cortana notify the user when the change is triggered (either with speech or via a new item on her dashboard) without a user specifically asking her?

Answer (score 0):

I was (and still "is", actually) also very interested in this kind of things, but as far as I could see it the only Cortana-related API lives in [Windows.ApplicationModel.VoiceCommands](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.voicecommands.aspx) namespace and **there is nothing** there to *invoke* Cortana, only handle voice command *from* Cortana.

So, hopefully Microsoft will either extend this or separate namespace in the future *OR* make Cortana available via [cross app communication](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2015/09/22/using-cross-app-communication-to-make-apps-work-together-10-by-10/).