# Is there a way to push content to Cortana without user initiation?

Tags: bots, cortana, cortana-skills-kit

Before anyone marks this question as a dupe, let me say I am aware of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30617188/is-there-any-way-to-invoke-a-cortana-response-without-user-input) from 2015. But Microsoft has done a lot of work on Cortana in the last two years so I thought it might be worth asking again. Please forgive me if this is not proper etiquette and feel free to educate me on how I should have handled asking the quesiton again.

I am currently writing a new skill for Cortana using, of course, the Microsoft Bot Framework. I've gotten everything registered and working except my actual interaction with Cortana. For this, I need Cortana to be able to *initiate* a conversation without the user prompting it. In 2015, this was not available. Is there currently a way to do so in the latest iteration of the platform? I can't seem to find it but I could be simply missing something subtle.

Answer (score 1):

The Cortana Skills kit currently does not support proactive notifications, however it is on the feature request list and will be considered.